# How to embed a series of .u3d models into PDF using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, 3d, acrobat

I want to embed 3D models into the same field(3D annotation), which means the model tree can display a series of meshes. I have read the Sdk document four days. But I can't find the API to create a 3D annotation or embed a series of 3D meshes into PDF.

Could anyone know it? I need your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow but in order to find quality help you will need to provide more information than that. It is not super clear what you are trying to achieve or what you have already tried. Please visit this link for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The Acrobat JavaSCript API cannot create new 3D annotations. Additionally, even if created, it cannot swap out models programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply joelgeraci!!!Do you know other ways that may embed a series of 3D models into PDF like Autodest Inventor? I want to write a program that can combine 18 stl files into a u3d file and embed it into PDF. So I can view the stl I choose in Model tree.

Comment: I have find a way to convert the stl file to u3d. But I can only embed a 3D model into the PDF.

Comment: Tetra4D is the company that Adobe has partnered with for 3D PDF